# How to make Ctrl-c to end the program

Tags: c, signals, interrupt

I want the program to test the trapping of the signal by typing CTRL+C to generate a signal of type SIGINT. I don't know, my program just counts to the first interrupt signal and ends the program (just jumps straight into the INThandler function)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void signalHandler( int signalValue ); /* prototype */
void  INThandler(int signalValue);


int main( void )
{
 int i; /* counter used to loop 100 times */
 int x; /* variable to hold random values between 1-50 */

 signal( SIGUSR1, signalHandler ); 
 signal(SIGUSR1, INThandler);
 srand( time( NULL ) );


    for ( i = 1; i <= 100; i++ ) {
        x = 1 + rand() % 50;

        if ( x == 25 ) {
            raise( SIGUSR1 );
        } 
        printf( "%4d", i );


        if ( i % 10 == 0 ) {
            printf( "\n" );
        } 
    }
  return 0; 
} 


void signalHandler( int signalValue )
{
  int response; 

  printf( "%s%d%s\n%s","\nInterrupt signal ( ", signalValue, " ) received.",
                     "Do you wish to continue ( 1 = yes or 2 = no )? \n" );

   scanf("%d", &response);
    if ( response == 1 ) {
        signal( SIGINT, signalHandler );
    }
    else {
    signal(SIGINT, INThandler);
    } 

}


void  INThandler(int signalValue)
{
  signal(signalValue, SIG_IGN);
  printf("\nCtrl-C command detected!");
  exit(0);

}
```

Comment: First you set `signalHandler` to handle `SIGUSR1`, then you set `INThandler` to handle it instead. What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Your code currently says:

```
signal(SIGUSR1, signalHandler); 
signal(SIGUSR1, INThandler);
```

The first call to `signal()` is effectively ignored.  You've installed `INThandler` as the signal handler for the `SIGUSR1` signals your program sends itself, and you have not installed any signal handler for `SIGINT`.

Comment: can't believe that I did such a stupid mistake, now it works.. thank you!

Comment: See also [How to avoid using `printf()` in a signal handler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler/16891799#16891799) for information about what you can and can't do in a signal handler.  Your signals are raised synchronously, not asynchronously, which reduces the risks involved drastically.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are doing with SIGUSR1.  If you want to setup a handler to trap SIGINT, just setup the signal handler with signal( SIGINT, signalHandler ).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void signalHandler( int signalValue ); /* prototype */
void  INThandler(int signalValue);


int main( void )
{
    int i; /* counter used to loop 100 times */
    int x; /* variable to hold random values between 1-50 */

    signal( SIGINT, signalHandler ); 
    srand( time( NULL ) );


    for ( i = 1; i <= 100; i++ ) {
        x = 1 + rand() % 50;

        if ( x == 25 ) {
            raise( SIGUSR1 );
        } 
        printf( "%4d", i );


        if ( i % 10 == 0 ) {
            printf( "\n" );
        } 
        fflush( stdout );
        sleep( 1 );
    }
  return 0; 
} 


void signalHandler( int signalValue )
{
    signal( SIGINT, signalHandler );
    int response; 

    printf( "%s%d%s\n%s","\nInterrupt signal ( ", signalValue, " ) received.",
                     "Do you wish to continue ( 1 = yes or 2 = no )? \n" );

    scanf("%d", &response);
    if ( response != 1 ) {
        signal(SIGINT, INThandler);
    } 
}


void  INThandler(int signalValue)
{
    signal(signalValue, SIG_IGN);
    printf("\nCtrl-C command detected!");
    exit(0);
}
```

```
1   2   3^C
Interrupt signal ( 2 ) received.
Do you wish to continue ( 1 = yes or 2 = no )? 
1
   4   5   6   7^C
Interrupt signal ( 2 ) received.
Do you wish to continue ( 1 = yes or 2 = no )? 
1
   8   9  10
  11  12^C
Interrupt signal ( 2 ) received.
Do you wish to continue ( 1 = yes or 2 = no )? 
1
  13  14  15  16  17^C
Interrupt signal ( 2 ) received.
Do you wish to continue ( 1 = yes or 2 = no )? 

2
  18  19  20
  21  22^C
Ctrl-C command detected!---
```